# Python re.finditer error at special characters

Tags: python-3.x

I have code that loops through a list of strings, then loops through each occurrence of that string inside another string. This seems to work until it reaches a string that begins with a question mark (? I).

This is the code.

```
dtID = 0
for datum in sorted(datumList, key=operator.attrgetter('Sum'), reverse = True):
    datum.ID = dtID
    for foundDatum in re.finditer(datum.Name, text):
        datumLocList.append(DatumLoc(dtID,foundDatum.start()))
    dtID += 1
```

How can I solve this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trist\Documents\Python\The Compressor\The Compressor.py", line 97, in <module>
    compress()
  File "C:\Users\trist\Documents\Python\The Compressor\The Compressor.py", line 73, in compress
    for foundDatum in re.finditer(datum.Name, text):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\re.py", line 230, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\sre_parse.py", line 930, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\sre_parse.py", line 651, in _parse
    source.tell() - here + len(this))
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern string containing a question mark is being treated as a regular expression special character. The ? symbol attempts to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding regular expression. Since in your string the ? is the first character, it is attempting to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding regular expression, which is nothing: hence your 'nothing to repeat at position 0' error.

To avoid this you can use the `re.escape()` method which will escape all RE special characters in your pattern string.

```
for foundDatum in re.finditer(re.escape(datum.Name), text):
    datumLocList.append(DatumLoc(dtID,foundDatum.start()))
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape